# Curl Kafka installation is not working in ubantu

Tags: linux, apache-kafka

i follow the below steps to install the kafka on the ubantu vm instance on google cloud and got the below error

```
mkdir ~/Downloads
curl "https://www.apache.org/dist/kafka/2.1.1/kafka_2.11-2.1.1.tgz" -o ~/Downloads/kafka.tgz
mkdir ~/kafka && cd ~/kafka
```

i get the below error when extract the kafka.tgz file

```
tar -xvzf ~/Downloads/kafka.tgz --strip 1
gzip: stdin: not in gzip format
tar: Child returned status 1
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

Where can I get the latest kafka.tgz link for the latest Kafka binary download and how do I fix the above tgz extract issue?

Comment: How about <https://kafka.apache.org/downloads>? More specfically, the latest binary build at <https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/3.2.1/kafka_2.13-3.2.1.tgz> linked at that exact same page. It's the first hit in your favorite search engines for the terms "kafka download"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Kafka 2.1.1 doesn't exist anymore in the [Apache mirrors](https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/), and is not the latest version.

There is no direct link to get `latest`, but you can get the URL through the links of the Apache Kafka homepage.

Here is how you would install version 3.2.1

```bash
KAFKA_VERSION=3.2.1
mkdir -p /opt/kafka_$KAKFA_VERSION \
  && curl -s https://downloads.apache.org/kafka/$KAFKA_VERSION/kafka_2.13-$KAFKA_VERSION.tgz \
  | tar -xvz --strip-components=1 -C /opt/kafka_$KAFKA_VERSION
ln -s /opt/kafka_$KAFKA_VERSION/ /opt/kafka

# TODO: add kafka unix user and chown the folder(s)
```

Alternatively, you could run Kafka as a Docker container or [install Confluent Platform with apt-get](https://docs.confluent.io/platform/current/installation/installing_cp/deb-ubuntu.html), which will include SystemD scripts for managing Kafka, Zookeeper, and more.